# iOS: How Do IAP's Work?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I was wondering how I give the user the new add-ons after they purchase them. Lets say that one of my IAP's is a new tab in a tab-based application. I'm under the impression that the process is something like this:

1. Submit an update to my app, adding in the IAP support.
2. Submit my app to iTunes Connect's "Manage IAP's", with the new tab implemented in the program.
3. When the user clicks "Buy Now" in the IAP screen, the app will grab the version of itself with that feature implemented off of iTunes Connect.

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm having a hard time wording what I'm trying to say. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 3 is wrong. The user will download the version of your application that supports both IAP and the new tab feature. Your app itself will have to determine whether to show the tab or not.

That is, when the user makes the purchase, you show the tab. There won't be two separate versions of your application on iTunes.

Depending on the purchase type, you can store a local flag or receipt on the device indicating that the user has purchased something. The next time your app runs, you check the flag or receipt and then show the tab only if the user had purchased the feature.

See: [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)